# Windows Forms ListView runtime errors

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to manage data by transferring ListViewItem objects from different ListViews (All of them are created on runtime)

And I'm facing a number of odd errors.
Running this loop:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
{
    this.view.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
}
```

gives me this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

And this code:

(Moving an item object from one list to another while ensuring other threads are not accessing the same lists)

```
while (this.backEnd.isUpdating && this.passive.isUpdating) ;
this.backEnd.isUpdating = true;
this.passive.isUpdating = true;
this.backEnd.Items[i].Remove();
this.passive.Items.Add(this.backEnd.Items[i]);
this.backEnd.isUpdating = false;
this.passive.isUpdating = false;
```

gives me this error:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Cannot add or insert the item '54d' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.
Parameter name: item
```

What could cause these issues and how can I fix them? Thank you

Comment: Your `while` loop is very wrong.

Comment: @SLaks why is that?

Comment: If you don't use threads, it makes no sense; if you do, it will kill your CPU and freeze your UI.  Use `await`.

Comment: What's the stack trace?  It sounds like you may have threading problems.

Comment: I added that while loop in order to stop threads running in the background just to prove that the issue is not due to other threads,  
By the way, what is await?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async.  You need to learn more about writing thread-safe code.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely learn that and implement, though would that solve my errors?

Comment: @SLaks When usign task.run I get an error listview accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on