# Visual Studio C# index errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I'm running this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
     if (list[i].Text.Equals(pid))
     {
        //....
     }
}
```

I get an error 'index out of bounds', but when using the debugger I can see that:

```
list.Count = 56
i=55
```

What's causing this error? it seems illogical.

Edit: As requested, a more detailed piece of code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list != null)
                {
                    **if (list[i] != null)
                    {
                        if (list[i].Text.Equals(pid))
                        {
                            return i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

List is from a listView.Items
The marked line is where the error is.
And again, the values are:

```
list.Count = 258
i = 257
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewNativeItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 displayIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at CANsniffer.Form1.FindPID(ListViewItemCollection list, String pid) in x/Form1.cs:line 170
   at CANsniffer.Form1.parseData(String inData) in x\Form1.cs:line 295
   at CANsniffer.Form1.DataReceivedHandler(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) in x/Form1.cs:line 408
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.CatchReceivedEvents(Object src, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.CallReceiveEvents(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

And if I use watch to see the values of list, I get:

```
ActualValue: null
Message: index was out of range
```

Also, these issues are somewhat related to this post: [Windows Forms ListView runtime errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230137/windows-forms-listview-runtime-errors)

Comment: @S.Akbari might be, although I've saw that value on the i located at list[i] so why would it show that? Also, how would it be possible that it's value be more than list.Count? that's are the for's checkups

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? Are you modifying the list in other threads? Without more information, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: I've tried stopping all other threads by putting them in a while loop, while this loop is running, same results.

Comment: Whatever your error is, it is not included in the information you provided. Everything you posted is fine, so please provide more information if you still need help

Comment: As Jerome said there's nothing wrong with the above code, something is happening elsewhere ('i' being modified for example).

Comment: Okay, I've added more detail.. hope it helps! @d219

Comment: Worth posting the complete exception stack trace?  Is it definitely the line with the asterisks?  Like 100% sure?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Done

Comment: If you just run the code above it runs fine (I've done it on a list object rather than a list view but I don't see an issue); when you run your actual code are you doing anything other than returning 'i'? If so just return i and see if it still crashes

Comment: Also you mentioned other threads in a comment above, are you sure they have stopped and are not altering the listview?

Comment: Each time I run the code, the error can appear in a different line, different function. On the listview there are two main processes that are modifying it: timer events and serial events. I've put a static boolean that sets true while serial event is active, and on the timer event if the boolean is true it exits the function. @d219 when should I return i?

Comment: You could simplify your code by using the List<T>.FindIndex method.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please publish your project on a shared store where I can download it and try to help you.

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer Okay I will try to implement that, though would that solve my issue? And it seems that my list has only Find function and not FindIndex

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer I tried using list.Find and it throws the error "arguementoutofrange"

Comment: You could try to add a .ToList() or .ToArray() to the ListView.Items property.
This way you will have a copy and eliminate the risk, that another thread is modifying the list at the same time.

Comment: The DataReceived event handler runs on a worker thread.  You cannot access ListView items safely in such code.  This kind of bug is usually detected with an InvalidOperationException, but it uses a heuristic that is not always capable of detecting such bugs.  You **must** use Control.Begin/Invoke() to run such code on the UI thread.  Or separate the view from the data so you can inject a `lock` to do this safely.

Comment: @HansPassant Im using a listView created on runtime and not UI and then update the UI list from it using a timer and flags.
Although, it could still cause this issue, but woudln't beginInvoke cause the whole runtime to be extremely slow?

Comment: Speed should not be of any practical concern, UI is meant for human eyes and they are incapable of reading that fast.  A pretty common mistake in SerialPort related code is to focus too much on displaying data instead of processing data, usually in an effort to assert that the code is correct.  In practice that doesn't work all that well and causes *more* bugs instead of less since it is pretty hard to deal with a firehose of data.  "using a listView created on runtime" is hard to make sense of, only ever use ListView to implement UI.

Comment: I believe it’s more or less clear that you have a thread safety issue here. I’d put aside any performance consideration for a while and try either iterating within lock(list) {...} block or over array obtained from list.ToArray() just to check if the error would have gone.
Take a look at this post it may be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622/threadsafe-foreach-enumeration-of-lists

Comment: Okay, I will try to implement that and update. thank you all.